# Why am I getting a 415 {detail: 'Unsupported media type "applicaton/json" in request.'} error

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I am making a post request to my Django rest framework backend but I keep getting a 415 error when I make the fetch request from React.

The request works perfectly when I make it from Django Rest Framework but I get 415 error when I make the POST request from React

views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def PaymentCreateView(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = PaymentSerializer(data=request.data)
            
    if serializer.is_valid():
                
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

React

```
const Support = async () => {
     
      const response =  await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/support/payment-create/',{
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "applicaton/json",
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
          "user": user,
          "email": email,
          "phone_number": phone_number,
          "number_of_apples": number_of_apples,
          "amount": amount,
          "message": message,
          
      })
      })

      let data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)
    }

     useEffect(() => {
        userpage()
      }, [])


      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        Support()
        e.preventDefault()
    }
```

error
[error][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUWI4.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo `applicaton/json` -> `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your  headers as following

export const login =(email, password, csrftoken) => async dispatch =>{

```
const config ={ headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
}
```

}`

```
const body = JSON.stringify({email: email, password:password})
```

axios.post(
`url`, body,config
).then((response)=> {}).
catch((err) =>{})